# What is the best way to save edit the form before submitting

Tags: python, django, django-forms

what is the best way to edit form before saving especially using the CreateView CBV

1) in the `form_valid()` function as the following code:

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        print(form.instance)
        print(form.instance.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

in the previous code when i `print(form.instance)` before i assigned any thing to it it gives `None` what `instance` represents in this code

2) in the `save()` function for the ModelForm as the following code:

```
     def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super().save(commit=False)
        print(instance)
        if self.request.user and instance.user is None:
            instance.user=self.request.user
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

Comment: I personally prefer second solution for setting `instance.user`

Comment: thanks, @aliva for you answer, and what **instance** refers to in the documentation